# Phone borked after clearing dalvik cache

Tags: cache, dalvik

On my Huawei G300, I cleared the dalvik cache from CWM and on rebooting, Android recreated it as expected but once the OS finished loading, all the apps started throwing up "Unfortunately x has stopped" and in particular Google Keyboard is doing that every 5s or so. On the first boot, it then dropped back to the Android boot animation, so I pulled the battery, rebooted into CWM and cleared the dalvik cache again and after that, at least it hasn't done that.

From System Settings - Apps I can see that Internal Storage only has 12MB free and 744MB used (it was actually 84KB free at first!). System Settings - Storage shows the Internal Storage has 137MB Free and 2.05GB Total though, so I guess they're referring to different things by "Internal Storage".

I use Link2SD and so most of my apps are linked to the 2GB Internal storage. I also have a 32GB SD card installed.

So if anyone could advise what I can do to fix this screwup, I'd be grateful as it's unusable at the moment. I managed to get Titanium Backup to run and update my backup, so I've got a current backup of my apps and data. ES File Explorer works as well but not much else.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I managed to uninstall some apps to free up some space and then after rebooting, I was able to use Link2SD to move the Dalvik Cache, which gave me about 230MB free instead of 12MB!

I still had some problems so cleared the Dalvik cache again but that put it back on the Internal Storage and used up all the free space again, so I had to uninstall a few more apps and move it again but at least it's usable now. I'm getting a new phone this week anyway, so I won't waste much time getting it perfect, as I'll just wipe it and reinstall a clean ROM before giving it to a friend.

Comment: Glad to hear it!